# InDesign Endnote Automation

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript, grep-indesign

I'm using this simple script to grab text wrapped in `[ENDNOTE][/ENDNOTE]` tags and make them into actual InDesign endnotes. The problem I'm having is that only the first 4 characters are being placed between the endnote markers (see screenshot below), any idea why this is happening, or how to make it work right?

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

function footnoteToEndnotes () {
    app.findGrepPreferences = null;
    app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = '\\[ENDNOTE\\](.+?)\\[\\/ENDNOTE\\]';
    var endnote,
        fnotes = doc.findGrep();

    for (var i = fnotes.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var taggedText = fnotes[i].contents.replace('[ENDNOTE]', '').replace('[/ENDNOTE]', '');
        endnote = fnotes[i].insertionPoints[0].createEndnote();
        endnote.texts[0].contents = taggedText;
        fnotes[i].remove();
    }
}

if (parseInt (app.version) < 13) {
    alert ('This script requires InDesign CC2018 or later');
    exit();
}

doc.endnoteOptions.frameCreateOption = EndnoteFrameCreate.NEW_PAGE;
footnoteToEndnotes();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, when I set the content of `insertionPoints[0]`, the full endnote ended up inside the endnote markers. But, there was an extraneous tab character at the end of the string... I stripped it out and it's working like I want!

I replaced this line:

```
endnote.texts[0].contents = taggedText;
```

With these:

```
endnote.texts[0].insertionPoints[0].contents = taggedText;
endnote.texts[0].contents = endnote.texts[0].contents.replace('\t', '');
```